# How to convert a Java Object to a String?

Tags: java, object, tostring

My DAO gets information from the database using this line of code.

```
public Object[] getTagData() {
    List TagData = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT sub.name, count(st.tags_tagId) as tagCount FROM subject as sub LEFT JOIN subject_tag  st on st.subject_subjectId = sub.subjectId GROUP BY sub.name;")
            .getResultList();

  return TagData.toArray();
}
```

It returns

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@27d027d

I need to convert this into a String so that I know in what form it will return.

Comment: You can pass your DAO in createNativeQuery as second parameter, and overrride toString of it.

Comment: @lexicore this is not a String array, it is an 2 dimensional object array

Comment: @Optional I completely missed the first line of the question :-| I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the result is not being stored in an Entity then it is being returned as an Object array, or rather an `Object [][]`

use a debugger and inspect the object you will see that `TagData[0][0]` contains the first column of the first row

Either you can create a specialized Entity for it and use it as per [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class))

or just iterate the two dim array